# using route/files vs route/resources in ring / compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

What is the difference in using -

```
(route/files "/" {:root "yeoman/app"})

(route/resources "/" {:root "yeoman/app"})
```

for setting the root of the static folder ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 8):

`resources`, like `clojure.java.io/resource`, will work relative to your classpath and can get your data even if its in a jar/war instead of on the local file system.